# Search String takes a long time the first time only?

Tags: c#, string, performance

No shortage of search for string performance questions out there yet I still can not make heads or tails out of what the best approach is.

Long story short, I have committed to moving from 4NT to PowerShell. In leaving the 4NT I am going to miss the console super quick string searching utility that came with it called FFIND. I have decided to use my rudimentary C# programming skills to try an create my own utility to use in PowerShell that is just as quick.

So far search results on a string search in 100's of directories across a few 1000 files, some of which are quite large, are FFIND 2.4 seconds and my utility 4.4 seconds..... after I have ran mine at least once????

The first time I run them FFIND does it near the same time but mine takes over a minute? What is this? Loading of libraries? File indexing? Am I doing something wrong in my code? I do not mind waiting a little longer but the difference is extreme enough that if there is a better language or approach I would rather start down that path now before I get too invested.

Do I need to pick another language to write a string search that will be lighting fast

I have the need to use this utility to search through 1000 of files for strings in web code, C# code, and another propitiatory language that uses text files. I also need to be able to use this utility to find strings in very large log files, MB size.

```
class Program
{
    public static int linecounter;
    public static int filecounter;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //
        //INIT
        //
        filecounter = 0;
        linecounter = 0;
        string word;
        // Read properties from application settings.
        string filelocation = Properties.Settings.Default.FavOne;
        // Set Args from console.
        word = args[0];
        //
        //Recursive search for sub folders and files
        //
        string startDIR;
        string filename;
        startDIR = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
        //startDIR = "c:\\SearchStringTestDIR\\";
        filename = args[1];
        DirSearch(startDIR, word, filename);

        Console.WriteLine(filecounter + " " + "Files found");
        Console.WriteLine(linecounter + " " + "Lines found");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static void DirSearch(string dir, string word, string filename)
    {
        string fileline;
        string ColorOne = Properties.Settings.Default.ColorOne;
        string ColorTwo = Properties.Settings.Default.ColorTwo;
        ConsoleColor valuecolorone = (ConsoleColor)Enum.Parse(typeof(ConsoleColor), ColorOne);
        ConsoleColor valuecolortwo = (ConsoleColor)Enum.Parse(typeof(ConsoleColor), ColorTwo);

        try
        {
            foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(dir, filename))
            {
                StreamReader file = new StreamReader(f);
                bool t = true;
                int counter = 1;
                while ((fileline = file.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    if (fileline.Contains(word))
                    {
                        if (t)
                        {
                        t = false;
                        filecounter++;
                        Console.ForegroundColor = valuecolorone;
                        Console.WriteLine(" ");
                        Console.WriteLine(f);
                        Console.ForegroundColor = valuecolortwo;
                        }
                        linecounter++;
                        Console.WriteLine(counter.ToString() + ". " + fileline);
                    }
                    counter++;
                }
                file.Close();
                file = null;
            }
            foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(dir))
            {
                //Console.WriteLine(d);
                DirSearch(d,word,filename);
            }

        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Just a suggestion, but if you get desperate, there is a tool called grep that is indispensable in fast string searching.

Comment: Local directory or a network resource? Primary HDD or a secondary one that may have power-save options (such as turn off after N minutes, etc.)? Do you run FFIND then try yours (or vise verse?) Also, if FFIND uses unmanaged code it's almost always going to be faster than loading up .NET.

Comment: There are so many existing "find all instances of a string in a bunch of files" programs that writing your own isn't worth it, particularly if you're looking for performance.  (As a learning experience, sure, but otherwise don't bother.)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to speed up your code run a performance analysis and see what is taking the most time. I can almost guaruntee the longest step here will be

```
fileline.Contains(word)
```

This function is called on every line of the file, on every file. Naively searching for a word in a string can taken len(string) * len(word) comparisons.

You could code your own Contains method, that uses a faster string comparison algorithm. Google for "fast string exact matching". You could try using a regex and seeing if that gives you a performance enhancement. But I think the simplest optimization you can try is :

Don't read every line. Make a large string of all the content of the file.

```
StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(filePath, Encoding.UTF8);
string text = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
```

Run contains on this.

If you need all the matches in a file, then you need to use something like [Regex.Matches(string,string)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b9712a7w.aspx).

After you have used regex to get all the matches for a single file, you can iterate over this match collection (if there are any matches). For each match, you can recover the line of the original file by writing a function that reads forward and backward from the match object index attribute, to where you find the '\n' character. Then output that string between those two newlines, to get your line.

This will be much faster, I guarantee it.

If you want to go even further, some things I've noticed are :

Remove the try catch statement from outside the loop. Only use it exactly where you need it. I would not use it at all.

Also make sure your system is running, ngen. Most setups usually have this, but sometimes ngen is not running. You can see the process in process explorer. Ngen generates a native image of the C# managed bytecode so the code does not have to be interpreted each time, but can be run natively. This speeds up C# a lot.

**EDIT**

Other points:
Why is there a difference between first and subsequent run times? Seems like caching. The OS could have cached the requests for the directories, for the files, for running and loading programs. Usually one sees speedups after a first run. Ngen could also be playing a part here, too, in generating the native image after compilation on the first run, then storing that in the native image cache.

In general, I find C# performance too variable for my liking. If the optimizations suggested are not satisfactory and you want more consistent performance results, try another language -- one that is not 'managed'. C is probably the best for your needs.

Comment: Loading entire files into memory might turn out to be a bad idea once you hit a really huge file. Further the OS will not read the file line by line but (pre)load entire pages and therefore loading bigger chunks will not yield as much improvement as one might expect. Searching files is almost always I/O bound - you can skim through a lot of memory while reading a page from a disk. And finally I doubt that using regular expression might speed things up. It is possible to compile a regular expression into a efficient state machine, but you can't beat a fast string search.

Comment: And this does not answer the question asked - why is there this significant difference in execution speed between the first and consecutive runs.

Comment: Maybe you should try it Daniel.

Comment: It does not answer the question asked? Very well.

Comment: I have no good idea where this difference in execution speed comes from - caching effects, maybe a small bit from JIT compiling, hard to tell without performing a few tests. There are a lot of open questions as mentioned in the comments to the question. For example to get reliable result one would probably have to perform one measurement, reboot the system and measure again to avoid (most) caching effects.

Comment: Yes I agree. By the way how did you get a hat on your profile? I want one. One must do one's best to answer the questions. Otherwise it would be a question-open-question site, and not a question-answer site. Haha.

Comment: Just click on Winter Bash in the top bar to the left of your user name.

Comment: Thanks. I clicked there but it seems I need to discover that hats. How unfun. No free hats.

Comment: I have considered just keeping 4NT to FFIND with PS. However thought it would be nice to make my own functionality.

I knew about grep but thought that was a non windows tool? 

I am on dev machine with both local HD and against servers on remote HD. I can also try rebooting before each test.

Thanks for the current responses I will test tomorrow at work and report back. :)